# Add data to gridview, from textbox, on button click

Tags: asp.net, vb.net, gridview, dynamic

I am working on an aspx site that lets an admin-level user fill out a form with potential member data. Once the form is filled out, the user will click submit and the data will go off to different tables. One part of the form that is stumping me involves filling out three textboxes (txtFirstName, txtLastName, txtGrade). I have a button (btnAddStudent), that, when clicked, should add the information from the textboxes to a table-like display area. I am trying to use a gridview, but there is nothing to bind it to. There is no memberID number to load a blank record from the Student table (which is a many-to-one relation to Member table). The member record is what this form is creating, and the student data will be added to the Student table when the Submit button is clicked.

I am currently working with the code found in the reply  [here](http://forums.asp.net/t/1411113.aspx). But when I click the "Add Student" button, I get a new blank row, but my textbox values are not inputted in the gridview.

Can this work, or do I need to look at using a table and adding rows of textboxes dynamically?

Here is relevant source code:

```
<tr>    
   <td class="style8">
    <asp:Label ID="Label18" runat="server" Text="Chidren:" Font-Bold="True" Font-                     Underline="True" Font-Names="Tahoma"></asp:Label>
  </td>
</tr>
<tr>
  <td class="style8">
    <asp:Label ID="Label19" runat="server" Text="First Name:"></asp:Label>
  </td>
  <td class="style7">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChildFirstName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
  </td>
  <td class="">
    <asp:Label ID="Label20" runat="server" Text="Last Name:"></asp:Label>
  </td>
  <td class="style6">
    <asp:TextBox ID="txtChildLastName" runat="server" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
   </td>
   <td class="style5" align="right">
     <asp:Label ID="Label21" runat="server" Text="Grade:"></asp:Label>
   </td>
   <td class="style4">
     <asp:TextBox ID="txtGrade" runat="server" Width="52px" CssClass="textbox"></asp:TextBox>
   </td>
   <td>
     <asp:Button ID="btnAddChild" runat="server" Text="Add Child" OnClick="btnAddChild_Click" />
   </td>
</tr>
<tr>
   <td valign="top" class="style8">
     <asp:Label ID="Label22" runat="server" Text="Student List:"></asp:Label>
   </td>
   <td colspan="3">
     <asp:UpdatePanel ID="UpdatePanel1" runat="server">
       <ContentTemplate>
         <asp:GridView ID="gvStudentList" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                                            PageSize="5" Height="42px">
                                            <AlternatingRowStyle BackColor="#E0E0E0" />
            <Columns>
               <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="FirstName" HeaderText="First Name" />
               <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="LastName" HeaderText="Last Name" />
               <asp:BoundField AccessibleHeaderText="Grade" HeaderText="Grade" />
            </Columns>
          <HeaderStyle BackColor="#CCCCCC" Height="25px" />
          <RowStyle Height="22px" />
         </asp:GridView>
       </ContentTemplate>
     </asp:UpdatePanel>
```

And the Code Behind:
     'A method that will BIND the GridView based on the TextBox
    'values and retain its values on post backs.

```
Private Sub BindGrid(rowcount As Integer)
    Dim dt As New DataTable()
    Dim dr As DataRow
    dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("FirstName", GetType([String])))
    dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("LastName", GetType([String])))
    dt.Columns.Add(New System.Data.DataColumn("Grade", GetType([String])))

    If ViewState("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
        For i As Integer = 0 To rowcount
            dt = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentData"), DataTable)
            If dt.Rows.Count > 0 Then
                dr = dt.NewRow()

                dr(0) = dt.Rows(0)(0).ToString()
            End If
        Next
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr(0) = txtChildFirstName.Text
        dr(1) = txtChildLastName.Text
        dr(2) = txtGrade.Text

        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    Else
        dr = dt.NewRow()
        dr(0) = txtChildFirstName.Text
        dr(1) = txtChildLastName.Text
        dr(2) = txtGrade.Text


        dt.Rows.Add(dr)
    End If

    ' If ViewState has a data then use the value as the DataSource 
    If ViewState("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
        gvStudentList.DataSource = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentData"), DataTable)
        gvStudentList.DataBind()
    Else
        ' Bind GridView with the initial data assocaited in the DataTable 
        gvStudentList.DataSource = dt

        gvStudentList.DataBind()
    End If
    ' Store the DataTable in ViewState to retain the values 
    ViewState("CurrentData") = dt

End Sub

Protected Sub btnAddChild_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles btnAddChild.Click
    ' Check if the ViewState has a data assoiciated within it. If 
    If ViewState("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
        Dim dt As DataTable = DirectCast(ViewState("CurrentData"), DataTable)
        Dim count As Integer = dt.Rows.Count
        BindGrid(count)
    Else
        BindGrid(1)
    End If
    txtChildFirstName.Text = String.Empty
    txtChildLastName.Text = String.Empty
    txtGrade.Text = String.Empty

    txtChildFirstName.Focus()
End Sub
```

With "BindGrid()" being called in the Page_Load event. (And yes, I have ScriptManager)

Comment: can you provide code? it will convey more information than paragraphs of text.

Answer (score 0):

Try to use

```
 Session("CurrentData") = dt on your BindGrid()
```

Then Create Method that just refreshes the grid after postback:

```
 Private Sub RefreshGrid()
 {
 If ViewState("CurrentData") IsNot Nothing Then
 gvStudentList.DataSource = DirectCast(Session("CurrentData"), DataTable)
 gvStudentList.DataBind()
 Else
 gvStudentList.DataSource = null;
 gvStudentList.DataBind()
 EndIf
 }
```

On your page load just call:

```
  If IsPostBack Then
            Return
     End If
     RefreshGrid()
```

Regards

Comment: I made these changes, and now it adds a blank row the first time, then nothing after each subsequent button click. Should I have changed all the "ViewState("CurrentData")" to Session? I only changed the one referenced in the comment. Thanks.

Comment: I changed all ViewState to Session. It adds rows now, but they are still blank. I will keep searching.